# Using Stripe with Grails 4

Tags: grails, stripe-payments, grails-4

I am having trouble installing the stripe plugin to Grails 4.

I added `compile "org.grails.plugins:stripe:2.10"` to the dependencies in the  build.gradle file.

Then used `grails install stripe` in the powershell.

I got this error:

````
| Error Error initializing classpath: Could not find org.grails.plugins:stripe:2.10.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/stripe/2.10/stripe-2.10.pom
  - https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/stripe/2.10/stripe-2.10.jar
Required by:
    project : (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)```
````

Comment: Here are very descriptive docs with examples: https://stripe.com/docs/api . imho it seems very user-friendly

Comment: "imho it seems very user-friendly" - @Michal_Szulc I don't think there is any info there that relates to resolving the error mentioned in the question.  The error is Grails specific and the error is caused becaus the author is trying to resolve a Grails 2 plugin in a Grails 3/4 app, which is not supported.

Comment: Of course, you are right. Just wanted to encourage an author to implement his own integration basing on the official docs (in fact he even asked about it under your answer)

Comment: Did a plugin recently which covers paypal/stripe/square https://plugins.grails.org/plugin/vahidhedayati/payment - hopefully it is easy enough to use embed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there isn't a version of that plugin which is compatible with Grails 4.  The code at https://github.com/bobbywarner/grails-stripe has not been updated in years.

There is no reason to run `grails install stripe` in Grails 4.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
Is there any other way to use Stripe with a Grails server?

Comment: "Is there any other way to use Stripe with a Grails server?" - Yes.  There are a number of options.  The Grails 2 plugin could be upgraded to support Grails 4.  You could use some library which provides integration with Stripe.  You could write the integration yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.